# Is there a way to run instrumented Android tests under mutation with gradle and pitest?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, mutation-testing

I have a set of instrumented Android tests which run on an emulated device. I can run them with  gradle using `gradlew connectedDebugAndroidTest`, and I've set up [gradle-pitest-plugin](https://github.com/koral--/gradle-pitest-plugin) like so:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    configurations.maybeCreate('pitest')
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath 'com.google.ar.sceneform:plugin:1.13.0'
        classpath 'pl.droidsonroids.gradle:gradle-pitest-plugin:0.2.2'
    }
}
```

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'pl.droidsonroids.pitest'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "my.application.id"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }
    }
    useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
    useLibrary 'android.test.base'
    useLibrary 'android.test.mock'
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Provides ARCore Session and related resources.
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.13.0'
    // Provides ArFragment, and other Sceneform UX resources:
    implementation "com.google.ar.sceneform.ux:sceneform-ux:1.13.0"

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:+"

    // AndroidX Test dependencies
    // Core library
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.0.0'

    // AndroidJUnitRunner and JUnit Rules
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.1.0'

    // Assertions
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:0.42'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-web:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:3.1.0'

    // The following Espresso dependency can be either "implementation"
    // or "androidTestImplementation", depending on whether you want the
    // dependency to appear on your APK's compile classpath or the test APK
    // classpath.
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.uiautomator:uiautomator:2.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-android:+"
    implementation 'org.pitest:pitest:1.4.5'
}

pitest {
    targetClasses = ['class.to.test.*']
    threads = 5
    outputFormats = ['HTML']
    verbose = true
}
```

When I run `gradlew pitest` or `gradlew pitestDebug`, the emulator doesn't start, and only my unit tests run. Specifying the instrumented test class in the `pitest` config or specifying a different test runner doesn't help. I'm new to Android Studio and configuring mutation testing with gradle, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple or this absolutely isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

Update: it's not possible without a PITest plugin, [according to the maintainer of gradle-pitest-plugin](https://github.com/koral--/gradle-pitest-plugin/issues/56).

Answer (score 0):

If you are test unitary your UI without need the instrumented mecanisme add like they said : If you are using alternative Android framework in tests, like Robolectric or UnMock Gradle Plugin, you may want to add excludeMockableAndroidJar to pitest configuration
`excludeMockableAndroidJar = true` -> For Robolectric

```
pitest {
targetClasses = ['com.myapp.*']
excludeMockableAndroidJar = true
```

}